# I want to know who is in the wrong....?

Tags: omaha

Playing online poker 2 nights ago I started the day a round 300$ up for the week... regardless I went on to dump the 300$...I then asked my friend to loan and send me 200$ this site is ran by 2 men and my best friend deals with a lot for them... so I was technically borrowing money from the two... which it is normal as of late for me I will borrow then pay it back... as I lost 1800$ the week before.. I’m not the best haha.... I ended up losing the 200$... Omaha was the game about 4-5 handed .50-1$ pot limit but the pot builds quick.... so I called my best friend up letting him know I would like 200$ more he was hesitant but I assured I’d put it in his bank the next day... what I am about to say I know is wrong but I was in a horrible spot cash wise after my week before... I had to loan from my family and the bank to pay my debt... so I asked my friend if he would join the table we would stay on the phone and collaborate it’s cheating it’s wrong... but I want to be honest with everything I’m asking... he had a lot of homework as he attends college and didn’t want to play but knowing my situation he finally made the decision to sit....we played for hours on the phone I’d build pots for him.....lay down hands give pots.... depending on the situation we were as strategic as we could... we said whoever had the best hand takes the pot...we did have a little splitting agreement obviously and then was established verbally... he kept letting me know he is ONLY playing because he wants to help me or he wouldn’t be playing I let him know I was great full and I appreciate it... I ended up building my stack about even from the beginning of the day which was great he was doing fine also... he did say and recommend I call it on the session but I wanted more.. my bankroll management is poor.... well it was early morning 4 of us remained at the table... my friend said hey man I have to call it a night I said thanks again talk to you tomorrow... we ended the phone call... he proceeded to remain at the table playing.. so one hand I believe 3 of us were still in on the river and it was a Big pot 350$ I’d say my buddy was first to act now mind you I have a very good hand and I knew it.... he then pots it the 3rd player folds... it is now on me I reluctantly let my hand go and immediately text him...the exact exchange was you’re welcome.... then... you owe me.... his response was thank you Rick.. I replied.... for real that was a lot of money... then... i was winning that hand... I laid it down because if I call he loses his stack and I was fine with where I was even though I could be really up.... I didn’t think much of it some hands later..... moral of the story another big pot around the same to the river it is us two left my action first I didn’t have a winning hand but I thought this is perfect I can pot it and he’d fold as I did for him.. I TEXT him before I bet.... fold... after it sent I potted it.... well he goes over the top!!!!???? I’d be stacked if I call and my hand wasn’t good.... I’m IRATE barely have any of my money now I’m way down again.... I was shaking with anger confused and felt betrayed and tilted as hard as possible I didn’t care.. my stack was basically gone so I just potted all i could ay pretty much all times the 3rd player leaves... I did manage to get to around 200$ but that isn’t anything if it was anyone else in his spot I win the first huge one and avoid the second! Here’s another kicker...As I’m playing with nothing but tilt my “best friend” continues to stay and stack me wasn’t hard with how I was playing... Now I’m 400$ in debt... I text him... you’re Gina loan me more to play... then... actually nevemind you just €%#+$& me I won’t be paying a dime of that 400$ you can pay it for how everything went down.... he try’s to justify he says I had the nuts what am I supposed to do? Well I said not long ago I handed you a 500$+ pot that I would’ve won but I folded for you... he asks why didnt you show it then....? Hahah ya let the other player I’m folding the nuts that’d be logical... the thing is he made it clear he was ONLY playing to help me then that conspired... we were playing together the whole night passing pots back and forth not that big but still.... he believes it’s fine I believe it’s total you know what... am I in the wrong here....?

TL:DR

I am in debt after borrowing from family, friends, and others. I decided to collude with a friend during an omaha game to make some money back. I passed my friend a large pot but when it was his time to pass me one, he screwed me over. He thinks he did nothing wrong, am I in the wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't cheat. Playing with the same exact player all the time and folding the nuts against him should get you banned within a day. Gamble responsibly and with your own money. Never borrow money, especially if you are a losing player. You said you were "in a horrible spot cash wise" since you "lost 1800$ the week before." You had to borrow money from your family to pay your debt and now you borrow more money to gamble. These are very serious gamble issues. I strongly suggest you to seek some help and never play poker again. It probably won't ever do you any good.

Comment: That money your friend won never belonged to you in the first place. You stole it from the other players by cheating. You shouldn't be upset about loosing it. You should be upset about your own actions.

Comment: This looks like a rant, and is really hard to read. Is there a TL:DR version?

Comment: @HerbWolfe i provide a TL:DR in my answer, ill edit the question as well

Comment: Even if you are going to cheat fold the winning hand is stupid.  You could fold KK to JJ to and lose to QQ.

Answer (score 4):

I'm glad that you came to this site to ask this question.

I'd like to boil down your question, because you provided a lot of background information that does not add a lot to the question.

You are essentially asking the following:

"I was colluding with a friend while playing Omaha. I let him win a big pot, but he did not do the same for me. Am I in the wrong?"

First of all, you were cheating. You stole money from other players who were playing fairly to cover some debt you recently acquired. This is unacceptable, and from that fact alone you are definitely in the wrong.

The way that you borrow money from friends and family to play high stakes that your bankroll can not support suggests to me that you have a gambling problem. You are clearly interested in the gamble over anything else. Do not take this as an insult, but rather as an opportunity to preform some self-evaluation.

Here is an article on gambling addiction, so you can educate yourself on what gambling addiction is and if it is something that you think you struggle with: https://www.casino.org/gambling-addiction/

If you suspect that you may be struggling with gambling addiction, you can find some links at this site that you may find useful: https://healthfinder.gov/FindServices/SearchContext.aspx?topic=337